# Consuming a Component Library that uses TailwindCSS

Tags: npm, vue-component, tailwind-css

We have a Component library (VueJS) that uses TailwindCSS which we are going to publish as a private npm package. The questions I have are

1. How do we also expose the `tailwind.config.js` in the Component Library so the consuming project can make use of the settings in the Component Library for example the colors in the consuming project's `tailwind.config.js`.
2. Is there a recommended way of "inheriting" the styles defined in the Component library?
3. And also since TailwindCSS V3 uses JIT to generate the classes, how do I also include the classes in the Component library?

Comment: Happy to find this question today, I'm wondering nearly the same thing. I don't have an answer, but wanted to share some ideas: my understanding is that if you ship Vue components that declare their TW styles, you just need the consumer of your library to run Tailwind's V3/JIT build and make sure it visits the files you shipped from your library. If that works as I think it would, then you would otherwise just need to make sure that any custom config you have in your tailwind.config.js gets inherited (say, `require`d and merged into a parent config) before build time. Just an idea, good luck!

Comment: Yeah I managed to `require("./node_modules/my-component-lib/tailwind.config")` and it works fine, i'm using wondering if there is a best practice way to do that? because it feels hacky...

Answer (score 6):

For 1 and 2 it looks like your component library could export a [Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins) that a consuming project would register in their own Tailwind config.

The second argument to `plugin()` can be any configuration your component libary wants to merge with the user's Tailconfig config.

E.g.

```js
// plugin.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

const myComponentLibraryConfig = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        salmon: 'salmon'
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = plugin(({ addUtilities, addComponents, e, config }) => {
  // Add your custom styles here
}, myComponentLibraryConfig),
```

When publishing your component library as a package, ensure the plugin is included.

Then, in your consuming project:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    //...
    plugins: [
        require('my-component-library/plugin')
    ]

}
```

For 3, it looks like you might need to explicitly add the location of your component library's components to the `content` section. E.g.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./node_modules/my-component-library/**/*.js",
        "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", // or whatever
    ]
}
```

The actual paths to things will depend on your project strucutures, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do exactly this not too long ago and we used rollup for our tailwind component library. I installed the copy plugin for rollup (from their official [plugin list](https://github.com/rollup/awesome)) and in my `rollup.config.js` I had something to this effect:

```js
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

const config = {
  plugins: [
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: "./tailwind.config.js",
            dest: "dist",
          }
        ]
      })
  ]
}
export default config;
```

So that copied that file into my output and I use that in whichever application is consuming this library like so:

```js
//tailwind.config.js
const commonConfig = require("component_library/dist/tailwind.config.js")
module.exports = { ...config }
```

and that works to solve #1 and #2 of your questions. I remember reading about this being supported somewhere in Tailwind documentation but can't remember where. You can also do overriding in your consumer app with basic destructuring like so:

```js
//tailwind.config.js
const commonConfig = require("component_library/dist/tailwind.config.js")

module.exports = {
  ...commonConfig,
  plugins: [
    ...commonConfig.plugins,
    require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp"),
  ],
}
```

As for question #3, I was able to go with @harryg 's method of just adding         `"./node_modules/my-component-library/dist/*.js"` to my tailwind.config.js in my component library and when I imported that config to the consumer app it was able to pick up all the needed styles/classes to compile without needing to export an entire tailwind stylesheet from the library. Hope this helped.

Comment: An alternative for Vite users is vite-plugin-static-copy. Not sure why this rollup plugin didn't work at all (Vite uses Rollup under the hood & has interop with many Rollup plugins), but I was able to get this Vite-specific plugin working fine. URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy

Answer (score 1):

I just accomplished this as part of a design system by providing the config in the dist folder:

**./src/assets/tailwind/config.js**

```
const content = [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
];

// theme values to be shared
const theme = {};

const plugins = [
    '@tailwindcss/line-clamp',
];

module.exports = {
    defaultContent: content,
    defaultTheme: theme,
    defaultPlugins: plugins,
};
```

**./tailwind.config.js**

```
const { defaultContent, defaultTheme, defaultPlugins } = require('./src/assets/tailwind/config');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    ...defaultContent,
  ],
  theme: {
    ...defaultTheme,
  },
  plugins: [
    ...defaultPlugins.map(plugin => require(plugin)),
  ],
}
```

Also I have a rollup build step that executes this:

```
"scripts": {
    "publish:lib": "normalstuff && node build-meta",
},
```

**./build-meta.js**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

fs.copySync(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/tailwind/config.js'), 'dist/assets/tailwind-defaults.js');
// I learned this technique from PrimeVue (so check their GitHub repo)
```

**consuming applications**

```
const { defaultContent, defaultTheme, defaultPlugins } = require('@yolo-inc/package-name/assets/tailwind-defaults');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    ...defaultContent,
  ],
  theme: {
    ...defaultTheme,
  },
  plugins: [
    ...defaultPlugins.map(plugin => require(plugin)),
  ],
}
```